# gstreamer debug builds

Tags: debugging, dll, gstreamer, debug-build

I m writing a multimedia application .For Debugging purpose I need  gstreamer debug builds for windows. Ossbuild only provides the release dll. Does anyone know where I can get debug dlls for gstreamer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to build it yourself, until the [Gstreamer SDK](http://code.entropywave.com/gstreamer-sdk/) comes out for Windows. Even if you managed to obtain debug DLLs, they would have to be from the same version of gstreamer that you're targeting with your release build, or else you'd get non-meaningful results when debugging.

If you used OSSBuild with Visual Studio, you may be able to find the .pdb files for debugging already in `$OSSBUILD/Build/Windows/Win32/Release/pdb` directory; if you can find these files, you can add them to Visual Studio so it knows to use them by following, e.g. [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instructions.

Reference for OSSBuild debug info: [here](http://www.gstreamer-winbuild.ylatuya.es/doku.php?id=developers)

Comment: Gstreamer SDK is available from gstreamer.com but unfortunately they bundle only release libraries. I have not compiled OSSBuild from visual studio so I dont have the .pdb files you have mentioned. I guess compiling from source remains the only option